# Avoiding re-authentication in filter if we click on reset button

Tags: java, servlets, filter, query-string

**Requirement:** When I click on Reset button in my web application then it should not show re authentication pop-up.

**HTML code:**

```
<button type="reset" onclick="reloadcurrentpage(false)">Reset</button>
```

**JS code**

```
function reloadcurrentpage(isAuthenticationRequired){

   window.location=window.location.href+"?isAuthenticationRequired"+isAuthenticationRequired;

}
```

I have UserAuthenticationFilter which sees that if page is already authenticated .This I am doing by storing boolean value to some variable in session scope when it goes into Controller.
Let me make you more clear. Let us suppose it is authenticated first time

**Controller code**

```
public class MyController{

   public Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request){
      request.getSession.setAttribute("isAuthenticated",true)
   }
}
```

**Filter code:**

```
  public class Fitler{

    doFilter(request,response,filterChain){

         if(request.getSession.getAttribute("isAuthenticated")){
             request.getSession.remove("isAuthenticated");
             fitlerChain.doFilter(request,response) ;
         }else{

             reponse.sendRedirect("showAuthenticationPopUp")
         }

    }//doFilter ends//

   }//filter class ends
```

**Approaches I followed to avoid re-authentication**

1)When I click on reset say URL forming is
**http.india.com/myController?isAuthenticationRequired=false** else other times it is **http.india.com/myController**

Now when I click on Reset button and write appropriate code in filter for this Query String I can avoid re-authentication, but problem is when I refresh the page then also re-authentication is avoided which should not happen. Reason for this is when I click on reset the url formed is
**http.india.com/myController?isAuthenticationRequired=false** so each time when I refresh the page it will avoid re authentication which would be another problem.

2)Second Approach I followed is when URL has that parameter then I called

```
response.redirect(request.getURI());
```

This removed by query string but it made me to authenticate page again.

3)Third Approach I followed is using Ajax request it worked for me but proved costly as I had to change 45+ files of re authentication and adjust the reponse.

Please suggest some way for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page loading I'm removing the URL from browser using history object.

```
if(location.search.contains("isAuthenticationRequired=false")){
  history.replaceState(null,documnent.title,location.pathname)
}
```